# React - React TransitionGroup CSSTransition migration from V5 to V6

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am doing a coursera's [React](https://www.coursera.org/learn/front-end-react/home/welcome) course, there them are using react V5 to develop the course but i decided to use V6 and deal with the problems that appear in order to learn the recent version, i am finishing it and encounter a problem that couldn't solve related to react animation in TransitionGroup and CSSTransition components. this is the code of the app in the V5 Course version:

**Index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';// this first for if i want to create own css
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))

reportWebVitals();
```

**App.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Main from './components/MainComponent';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {ConfigureStore} from './redux/configureStore';

const store= ConfigureStore();

class App extends Component {
  
  render(){
  return (
    
    //redux provider//
    <Provider store={store}>  
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Main />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
}
};

export default App;
```

**MainComponent.js V5:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Home from './HomeComponent';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import About from './AboutComponent';
import Contact from './ContactComponent';
import Header from './HeaderComponent';
import Footer from './FooterComponent';
import DishDetail from './DishdetailComponent';

import { Switch, Route, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { postComment, postFeedback, fetchDishes, fetchComments, fetchPromos, fetchLeaders } from '../redux/ActionCreators';
import { actions } from 'react-redux-form';
import { TransitionGroup, CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';


const mapStateToProps = state => {

    return{
        comments: state.comments,
        dishes: state.dishes,
        leaders: state.leaders,
        promotions: state.promotions,
    }
}       

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    postComment: (dishId, rating, author, comment) => dispatch(postComment(dishId, rating, author, comment)),
    
    
    fetchDishes: () => { dispatch(fetchDishes()) },
    resetFeedbackForm: () => { dispatch(actions.reset('feedback')) },
    
    fetchComments: () => dispatch(fetchComments()),
    
    fetchPromos: () => dispatch(fetchPromos()),
    fetchLeaders: () => dispatch(fetchLeaders()),
    
    
    postFeedback: (firstname, lastname, telnum, email, agree, contactType, message) => dispatch(postFeedback(firstname, lastname, telnum, email, agree, contactType, message)),

});


class Main extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchDishes();
        this.props.fetchComments();
        this.props.fetchPromos();
        this.props.fetchLeaders();
    }

    render() {

        const HomePage = () => {
            return (
                <Home
                    dish={
                        this.props.dishes.dishes.filter(dish => dish.featured)[0]
                    }
                    dishesLoading={this.props.dishes.isLoading}
                    dishErrMess={this.props.dishes.errMess}
                   
                    promotion={
                        this.props.promotions.promotions.filter(promo => promo.featured)[0]
                    }
                    promoLoading={this.props.promotions.isLoading}
                    promoErrMess={this.props.promotions.errMess}
                    
                    leader={
                        this.props.leaders.leaders.filter((leader) => leader.featured)[0]
                    }
                    leaderLoading={this.props.leaders.isLoading}
                    leaderErrMess={this.props.leaders.errMess}

                />
            );
        };






        const AboutUsPage = () => {
            return(
                <About 
                    leaders={this.props.leaders.leaders}
                    leaderLoading={this.props.leaders.isLoading}
                    leaderErrMess={this.props.leaders.errMess}
                />
            );
        };


        const DishWithId = ({match}) => {
            return(
                <DishDetail dish={this.props.dishes.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === parseInt(match.params.dishId, 10))[0]}
                    isLoading={this.props.dishes.isLoading}
                    errMess={this.props.dishes.errMess}
                    
                    comments={this.props.comments.comments.filter((comment) => comment.dishId === parseInt(match.params.dishId, 10))}
                    commentsErrMess={this.props.comments.errMess}
                    postComment={this.props.postComment}
                />
            );
        };



        return (
            <div>
                <Header></Header>

                <TransitionGroup>
                    <CSSTransition key={this.props.location.key} classNames="page" timeout={300}>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/home" component={ HomePage } />
                            <Route exact path="/menu" 
                                component={() => <Menu dishes={this.props.dishes}/> }
                            />

                            <Route path="/menu/:dishId" component={DishWithId} />

                            <Route exact path="/contactus" component={() => <Contact 
                                                                                resetFeedbackForm={this.props.resetFeedbackForm } 
                                                                                postFeedback={this.props.postFeedback}

                                                                            /> } 
                            />

                            <Route exact path="/aboutus" component={ AboutUsPage } />
                        
                            {/* if url dosesnt match, bydefault redirect to */}
                            <Redirect to="/home" />
                        </Switch>
                    </CSSTransition>
                </TransitionGroup>


                <Footer></Footer>
            </div> 
        );

    }

}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main));


/**
 * 
 * - connect(): generates a wrapper container component that 
 *      subscribe to the store.
 */
```

**Main Component V6 (mine):**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from './HomeComponent';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import Contact from './ContactComponent';
import DishDetail from './DishdetailComponent';
import Header from './HeaderComponent';
import Footer from './FooterComponent';
import About from './AboutComponent'
import {Routes, Route, Navigate, useParams, useNavigate, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'; //Switch changed to routes Also redirect is changed to Navigate since version 6
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { postComment, fetchDishes, fetchComments, fetchPromos } from '../redux/ActionCreators';
import { actions } from 'react-redux-form';
import {TransitionGroup, CSSTransition} from 'react-transition-group';

// --------Hook to use withRouter from v5 in actual v6-----------------
export const withRouter = (Component) => {
  const Wrapper = (props) => {
    const history = useNavigate();
    
    return (
      <Component
        history={history}
        {...props}
        />
    );
  };
  
  return Wrapper;
};
//------------End of Hook-----------------

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        dishes: state.dishes,
        comments: state.comments,
        promotions: state.promotions,
        leaders: state.leaders
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  postComment: (dishId, rating, author, comment) => dispatch(postComment(dishId, rating, author, comment)),
  fetchDishes: () => { dispatch(fetchDishes())},
  fetchComments: () => dispatch(fetchComments()),
  fetchPromos: () => dispatch(fetchPromos()),
  resetFeedbackForm: () => { dispatch(actions.reset('feedback'))}

});


class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchDishes();
    this.props.fetchComments();
    this.props.fetchPromos();
  }
  render(){

    const HomePage = () => {
      // console.log(this.props)
      return(
          <Home 
              dish={this.props.dishes.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.featured)[0]}
              dishesLoading={this.props.dishes.isLoading}
              dishesErrMess={this.props.dishes.errMess}

              promotion={this.props.promotions.promotions.filter((promo) => promo.featured)[0]}
              promoLoading={this.props.promotions.isLoading}
              promoErrMess={this.props.promotions.errMess}
              
              leader={this.props.leaders.filter((leader) => leader.featured)[0]}
              leaderLoading={this.props.leaders.isLoading}
              leaderErrMess={this.props.leaders.errMess}
          />
      );
    }

    const DishWithId = () => {
      let params = useParams();
      
      return(
          <DishDetail dish={this.props.dishes.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === parseInt(params.dishId,10))[0]}
            isLoading={this.props.dishes.isLoading}
            errMess={this.props.dishes.errMess}
            comments={this.props.comments.comments.filter((comment) => comment.dishId === parseInt(params.dishId,10))}
            commentsErrMess={this.props.comments.errMess}
            postComment={this.props.postComment}
          />
      );
    };
    const AnimatedSwitch = () => {
      const location = useLocation();
      console.log("location", location);
      return (
        <TransitionGroup>
          <CSSTransition key ={location.key} classNames='page' timeout = {3000}>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/home" element={<HomePage/>}/> {/*Also component must be changed to element since i am using V6*/}
              <Route exact path="/menu" element= {<Menu dishes={this.props.dishes} />} />  {/* in previous version this must look as: () => element= {<Menu dishes={this.props.dishes} />} */}
              <Route path = "/menu/:dishId" element={<DishWithId />} />
              <Route exact path ='/contactus' element={<Contact resetFeedbackForm={this.props.resetFeedbackForm}/>} />
              <Route path = '/aboutus' element={<About leaders = {this.props.leaders}/>} />
              <Route path="*"element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
              {/* Instead of redirect the above snippet is needed to redirect if there is no matched url */}
            </Routes>
          </CSSTransition>
        </TransitionGroup>
      );
    };
  return (
    
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <AnimatedSwitch/>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main));
```

I tried the solution of create a AnimatedSwitch component to use but the app doesn't throw error but the animation does not work, how can i achieve a solution to migrate V5 version to V6 correctly
This the **package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "confusion",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.1.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-popper": "^2.2.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-redux-form": "^1.16.14",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.2",
    "reactstrap": "^9.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
a
```